# ActiveRecord paginate returns empty results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, pagination

According to [will_paginate's documentation](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki), it should be able to invoke MyModel.paginate to load a page of results with SQL query that loads only the needed rows. But I always get back empty results even though the right query is performed (to the Oracle DB.) Doing the same with the array pagination would work. Why wouldn't the ActiveRecord::Base.paginate work? (Rails 2.3 / JRuby 1.7)

```
>> users = User.paginate(:all, :page => 1, :per_page => 10)
=> []
# query performed, verified correct: select * from (SELECT * FROM "USERS" WHERE ("USERS".is_deleted = 0 or "USERS".is_deleted is NULL)  ORDER BY id) where rownum <= 10
>> users.size
=> 0
>> users.total_entries
=> 0
# regular pagination over the result works but is not optimal as it loads all records
>> u2 = User.find(:all).paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 10)
=> [#<User user_id: 4015857, ...> ... ]
>> u2.size
=> 10
>> u2.total_entries
=> 32449
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I do not know of the exact reason which probably has to do with the older rails 2.3 and will_paginate version. The work around is easy: roll your own WillPaginate::Collection from the the AR finder results, like

```
# given page and per_page parameters
count = User.count(:all)
return WillPaginate::Collection.create(page, per_page, count) { |pager|
    pager.replace(User.find(:all, :offset => (page - 1) * per_page, :limit => per_page)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `:all` from the argument list:

```
users = User.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 10)
```